# Caching with Glide

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

I'm using Glide and want to cache loaded images to local memory.

I searched for the same, and found out that images are cached automatically. You just need to provide the same loadURL , and Glide will search for image (along with other provided attrs : Resolution, Key, etc). The problem that I'm facing is that, I know what the loadURL will be at the time of initial resource load. But when the app wants to load the cached copy of, it doesn't have any loadURL info. How can I load cached images without providing loadURL (which was same at the time of initial load). Can I use any key (say StringKey), which can be associated with the image at initial load, and use the same key (without loadURL) at the time of loading cached copy? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Glide doesn't support directly accessing the cache.
So, just persist the url the first time and use it later to load the cached image.

First time:

```
    Glide.with(this).load(url).into(image);
    save(url);
```

Later:

```
   String url = getUrl();
   Glide.with(this).load(url).into(image);
```